# How to deconfigure a Debian package

Tags: debian, dependencies

In the "Debian Policy Manual", under Chapter 7 there is a section titled "7.3 Packages which break other packages - Breaks". In that section is says (in part):

> When one binary package declares that it breaks another, dpkg will
>   refuse to allow the package which declares Breaks to be unpacked
>   unless the broken package is deconfigured first, and it will refuse to
>   allow the broken package to be reconfigured.

How do you "deconfigure" an installed Debian package?

Answer (score 0):

That means to un-install the offending package.

Comment: Why didn't they just say "uninstall", then?

Comment: @user35042 Take that up with the Debian project.

Comment: There’s no such thing as “un-install”. Does it mean call prerm, remove files, call postrm, …?